# Laravel file download issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm attempting to download a file uploaded to the `public` folder.

```php
$file = SVU::findByUuidOrFail(request('uuid'));
$user = auth()->user();
$file = public_path()."/files/download/".$file->file;

$download = Response::download($file, $file->file);
$user->reducePoint($file->points);

return $download;
```

The `reducePoint` function works just fine. The issue is when the user is downloading a file using a download manager like IDM (Internet Download Manager). The `reducePoint` function gets executed twice! I saw a question similar to the answer suggested to use `URL::signedRoute(),` but it's not doing anything besides generating a unique signature. Any ideas on how this issue could be solved?

Comment: Interesting question..